# Error Spring Boot : JSON parse error:Cannot construct instance of; no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor ....

Estoy trabajando con Spring Boot , NetBeans 12.6, Mysql.

. ____ _ __ _ _ /\ / ' __ _ () __ __ _ \ \ 
( ( )__ | '_ | '| | ' / ` | \ \ 
/ **)| |)| | | | | || (| | ) ) ) ) ' || .**|| ||| |_, | / / / / =========||==============|/=//// :: Spring Boot :: (v2.6.4)

Tengo dos clases Localiades y Domicilios, donde un campo de domicilios es una llave foránea, el idLocalidad, tengo problemas al crear un domicilio

```
Tengo la clase Localidad

@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "localidades") 

public class Localidad {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idLocalidad")
    private Long idLocalidad;
    private String codigoPostal;
    private String localidad;
    
  
    
     public Localidad() {
       super();
    }
    
   
       
    public Localidad(Long idLocalidad, String codigoPostal, String localidad) {
       super();
         this.idLocalidad = idLocalidad;
        this.codigoPostal = codigoPostal;
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }
  Otra clase Domicilio que tiene como llave foránea al idLocalidad

@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "domicilios") 

public class Domicilio {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idDomicilio")
    private Long idDomicilio;
    
    private String direccion;
    private String altura;
    
    
    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="localidadId", referencedColumnName= "idLocalidad", 
    nullable = false)
    private Localidad localidadId;
   
   
    
    public Domicilio() {
        super();
    }

    public Domicilio(Long idDomicilio, String direccion, String altura, Localidad 
    localidadId) {
        super();
        this.idDomicilio = idDomicilio;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.altura = altura;
        this.localidadId = localidadId;
    }

Repositorio Domicilio



      @Repository
      public interface DomicilioRepository extends JpaRepository<Domicilio,Long> {
    
    
      }


Interfaz  Localidad y Domicilio


public interface ILocalidadService {
    
    public List<Localidad> getLocalidad();
    
    public void saveLocalidad(Localidad loc);
        
    public void deleteLocalidad(Long idLocalidad);

    public Localidad buscarLocalidad(Long idLocalidad);
}



public interface IDomicilioService {
    
      public List<Domicilio> getDomicilio();
    
    public void saveDomicilio(Domicilio dom);
        
    public void deleteDomicilio(Long idDomicilio);

    public Domicilio buscarDomicilio(Long idDomicilio);
    
}



Servicio Localidad y Domicilio


@Service
public class LocalidadService implements ILocalidadService{
                                       
    @Autowired
    private LocalidadRepository locRepo;

    @Override
    public List<Localidad> getLocalidad() {
         List<Localidad> listaLocalidad = locRepo.findAll();
       return listaLocalidad;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveLocalidad(Localidad loc) {
        locRepo.save(loc);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteLocalidad(Long idLocalidad) {
        locRepo.deleteById(idLocalidad);
    }

    @Override
    public Localidad buscarLocalidad(Long idLocalidad) {
        Localidad loc = locRepo.findById(idLocalidad).orElse(null);
        return loc;
    }
    
}


@Service
public class DomicilioService implements IDomicilioService {
    
    @Autowired
    private DomicilioRepository domRepo;

    @Override
    public List<Domicilio> getDomicilio() {
       
       List<Domicilio> listaDomicilio = domRepo.findAll();
       return listaDomicilio;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveDomicilio(Domicilio dom) {
        domRepo.save(dom);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteDomicilio(Long idDomicilio) {
        domRepo.deleteById(idDomicilio);
    }

    @Override
    public Domicilio buscarDomicilio(Long idDomicilio) {
       Domicilio dom = domRepo.findById(idDomicilio).orElse(null);
       return dom;
    }

}

Controlador Domicilio

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class DomicilioController {
    
    @Autowired IDomicilioService domServ;
    @Autowired ILocalidadService locServ;
    private Localidad loc;     

    
     
   
  @PostMapping("/domicilio/crear")
   public String CrearDomicilio(@RequestBody Domicilio dom                               
                                ){
          
    Localidad local = locServ.buscarLocalidad(loc.getIdLocalidad());
        
    dom.setLocalidadId(local);
                                 
        domServ.saveDomicilio(dom);
       return "el domicilio fue creado exitosamente";
       
      
   }
  
     
   @PutMapping("/domicilio/editar/{idDomicilio}")
   
   public Domicilio editDomicilio(@PathVariable Long idDomicilio,
                              @RequestParam ("direccion") String nuevaDireccion,
                              @RequestParam ("altura") String nuevaAltura,
                              @RequestParam("localidadId") Localidad nuevaLocalidad
                              ){
       
       //buscamos el domicilio a modificar
       
       Domicilio dom = domServ.buscarDomicilio(idDomicilio);
       
       dom.setDireccion(nuevaDireccion);
       dom.setAltura(nuevaAltura);
       dom.setLocalidadId(nuevaLocalidad);
       
       
       domServ.saveDomicilio(dom);
       return dom;
   }
    
    
}
```

Cuando quiero crear un domicilio, me sale el siguiente error: "Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of com.desarrollo.portfolio.models.Localidad (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of com.desarrollo.portfolio.models.Localidad (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1) at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 4, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.desarrollo.portfolio.models.Domicilio["localidadId"])]"

Y en Postman:

Detalle

[image: postman]

Tal vez el error está en como defino el crearDomicilio, pero la verdad estoy empezando a programar con spring, java y no logro descubrirlo.

Comment: Si todavía necesitas una solución, adjunta el código de tu controller.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es dentro la declaración del modelo... en el constructor de la clase ya estás declarado con la anotación **@GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)** esta diciendo que el proveedor de persistencia (no sé si estás usando **Hibernate**) se encarga de la generación de ids, por lo tanto, en el constructor ya se debe iniciar con el código.

Al momento de crear en el controller estás tratado de buscar una localidad, pero la variable nunca se inicializa, lo que podrías hacer es en la cabeza utilizar la anotación @RequestParam o @PathVariable para tomar ese id desde la cabeza y mandarle a buscar si ya tiene unas localidades existentes o como estas utilizando mandarle directamente desde el cuerpo de la petición solo que le mandas a buscar usando el objeto que estás tomando como parámetro en la petición

```
Localidad local = locServ.buscarLocalidad(dom.getLocalidad());
```